# Replacing power cable of wall fan

Tags: fans

The original fan cable was damaged so i thought maybe i could cut it off and replace it with a cable and plug from an extension cable.

The wierd thing is, it worked for a while and now doesn't.

In the picture, there is voltage in all the connections and there is also a reading without voltage in the unconnected white wire. Nothing in the blue wire.

When i connect the white and blue wires (as i had before, and it worked for a while), then the white/blue connection gets no voltage at all and of course the fan doesn't turn.

Can anyone shed any light on any of this? Why no voltage in the white wire after i connect it to the blue one? Could another component have blown or something? There was never any smoke/burning at any stage.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

[image: the grey cable is original. The black cable is a replacement.]

This is the tester. It shows if there's voltage or just if there's a connection but no voltage.
[image]

Comment: how did you measure the current in the wires?

Comment: With one of those screwdrivers that has an LCD display that shows current when you touch the wire with the end of it.

Comment: that shows that there is a voltage ... it does not mean that current is flowing

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm learning as i go and have tried to edit my posts to change 'current' to 'voltage'. Do you think i need to get a new fan or could there be an easy fix?

Comment: I approved your edit but somehow you have gotten yourself two StackExchange accounts.  Hit "Flag"... "Moderator help"... and ask your accounts to be merged.  Also, this usually happens because you are using a passwordless "cookie-based" account; tying an account to an email or Facebook/Google will make that stop happening.

Comment: Small appliance repair is off-topic here. Sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

> In the picture, there is voltage in all the connections and there is also a reading without voltage in the unconnected white wire. Nothing in the blue wire.

Neutral is return.  It's supposed to be near zero (no detectable voltage).

That's normal.  The blue wire (Euro colors there) is the supply/source of neutral.  It better not read voltage!

> When i connect the white and blue wires (as i had before, and it worked for a while), then the white/blue connection gets no voltage at all and of course the fan doesn't turn.

When you connect the white wire to the blue wire, it correctly connects it to netural. Again, that should be near zero.  So far everything checks out.